# Invoking action method using Java script in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I have a form, I want to check the username is availability. I that I have html textbox, in Onclcik I'm calling java script function. The script has to call the Action methods in controller. Based upon the username availability it has to return either 1 or 0. I have tried Json. But its is showing "Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined". Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: add this below the `title` of the document `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js></script>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get that message it means you're trying to use jQuery but you haven't included the library. You can use [Google's CDN](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js). 
I guess you've used Ajax to call. Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
        url: '<%=Url.Action("Your Action", "Your Controller")%>',
    data: { userName: $('#UserName').val(), password: $('#Password').val() },
        dataType: 'json',
        complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
    // User your JSON response.
    }
});
```

If you're using a POST you have to decorate your action with the attribute `[HttpPost]`
and remember to specify `JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet` when you return your JSON object:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CheckUserName(string userName, string password)
{
    // notification: your object
    return (Json(notification, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Jquery (the $ sign), then that means that you need a script reference to jquery implementation before your javascript code that calls JSON.

```
script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Where jquery.js is the latest version of the jquery javascript file

Comment: So can u tell me which script I need to reference. In MVC project I have nearly 6 jquery scripts

Comment: Cool, thanks man, just for that, I'll vote you up too given that you've made more effort :-)